# Bookmarklet issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bookmarklet

I'm trying to get this bookmarklet running but I get this error (in Chrome):

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

I don't get what's wrong with my JavaScript code in the `href`. I can't put it in a separate file; I need to get this running in the `href`.

```html
    <a href="javascript:(function(){
      if (!($ = window.jQuery)) { 
        script = document.createElement( 'script' );
        script.src = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js'; 
        script.onload=releasetheScript;
        document.body.appendChild(script);
      } 
      else {
        releasetheScript();
      }
    
      function releasetheScript() {
        
        regex = ['ceo', 'fondateur', 'cofondateur', 'cto', 'cfo', 'daf', 'startup', 'entrepreneur', 'office manager', 'fintech', 'freelance', 'tech', 'founder', 'neobanque', 'banking', 'comptable', 'incubateur', 'coworking', 'PME', 'VC', 'accélérateur']
        banned = ['|(?!', 'sex', 'porn']
        target = regex.join('|') + banned.join('|') + ')';
        interval = 10000
        a = setInterval(function () {
          window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
          var fields = $('.ProfileCard-userFields');
          for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
            var p = fields[i].getElementsByClassName('ProfileCard-bio');
            if (p[0].textContent.length > 1) {
              if (p[0].textContent.match(new RegExp(target), 'g') !== null) {
                console.log(p[0].textContent, 'text matching')
              }
            }
          }
        }, interval);
      }
    })()">Bookmarklet</a>
```

Comment: Have you tried removing all the whitespace from the JavaScript code?

Comment: Have you tried testing your code without the `é` character, on the off chance that the browser has an issue with it? Which browsers have you tried this code in?

Comment: I'm using chrome browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add semicolons at the ends of all the statements, [ASI](http://www.bradoncode.com/blog/2015/08/26/javascript-semi-colon-insertion/) isn't filling them in where you need them. I'm not going to bother trying to figure out why, just get in the habit of always using them.

```html
    <a href="javascript:(function(){
      if (!($ = window.jQuery)) { 
        script = document.createElement( 'script' );
        script.src = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js'; 
        script.onload=releasetheScript;
        document.body.appendChild(script);
      } 
      else {
        releasetheScript();
      }
    
      function releasetheScript() {
        
        regex = ['ceo', 'fondateur', 'cofondateur', 'cto', 'cfo', 'daf', 'startup', 'entrepreneur', 'office manager', 'fintech', 'freelance', 'tech', 'founder', 'neobanque', 'banking', 'comptable', 'incubateur', 'coworking', 'PME', 'VC', 'accélérateur'];
        banned = ['|(?!', 'sex', 'porn'];
        target = regex.join('|') + banned.join('|') + ')';
        interval = 10000;
        a = setInterval(function () {
          window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
          var fields = $('.ProfileCard-userFields');
          for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
            var p = fields[i].getElementsByClassName('ProfileCard-bio');
            if (p[0].textContent.length > 1) {
              if (p[0].textContent.match(new RegExp(target), 'g') !== null) {
                console.log(p[0].textContent, 'text matching')
              }
            }
          }
        }, interval);
      }
    })()">Bookmarklet</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your bookmarklet will be run as a single line of script, so semicolons are not optional. Your script is failing because you're missing semicolons.

Two side notes:

- Your code is using implicit globals for seemingly no reason. Use `var` to declare variables.
- You're better off starting the script URL with `//` rather than `http://`, to ensure that the script is loaded regardless of the scheme of the local page.

```html
<a href="javascript:(function(){
  if (!window.$ || window.$ !== window.jQuery) { 
    var script = document.createElement( 'script' );
    script.src = '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js'; 
    script.onload=releasetheScript;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  } 
  else {
    releasetheScript();
  }

  function releasetheScript() {
    /* v--- need a semicolon on this line */
    var regex = ['ceo', 'fondateur', 'cofondateur', 'cto', 'cfo', 'daf', 'startup', 'entrepreneur', 'office manager', 'fintech', 'freelance', 'tech', 'founder', 'neobanque', 'banking', 'comptable', 'incubateur', 'coworking', 'PME', 'VC', 'accélérateur']; 
    var banned = ['|(?!', 'sex', 'porn'];  /* <-- here  */
    var target = regex.join('|') + banned.join('|') + ')';
    var interval = 10000;    /* <-- here  */
    var a = setInterval(function () {
      window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
      var fields = $('.ProfileCard-userFields');
      for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
        var p = fields[i].getElementsByClassName('ProfileCard-bio');
        if (p[0].textContent.length > 1) {
          if (p[0].textContent.match(new RegExp(target), 'g') !== null) {
            console.log(p[0].textContent, 'text matching');  /* <-- and here  */
          }
        }
      }
    }, interval);
  }
})()">Bookmarklet</a>
```